# Check whether a module is started as (unit-) test

Tags: python, python-import

I wrote my own module, let's call it `mymodule`. To improve whether it's working I wrote `tests`. So that's what the structure became:

```
django-mymodule
|-mymodule (.py files in here)
|-tests (.py files in here, they are unittests)
|-... (docs and this stuff)
```

When `module` is installed to my computer is has to use relative imports like this: `from . import otherfile`. When it is started as test, the imports have to look like this: `import otherfile`.
So I will have to do something like this:

```
if is_run_as_test:
  import otherfile
else:
  from . import otherfile
```

How does this `is_run_as_test` looks? Or am I doing something really wrong?

Comment: How will you test your code if it runs differently when you aren't testing it?

Comment: It doesn't run different, it's only because there are different ways to import for using `python3 -m unittest tests/test_file1` (in the shell) and when I have installed the module - as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/1622937

Comment: You can use absolute imports if your code is in a python package format, then you could run the tests from the project root.

Comment: I didn't understand your second post in the beginning, but now when I know what to do it's really clear. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by checking whether or not your testing framework has been imported.

It would be strange to have it imported in regular code, so one could assume that the code is being run during a test.

```
if 'unittest' in locals():
    print('I am being run within a test')
```

Comment: This looks good but didn't work to me. The imports (now) in `tests/file1`: `import unittest`, `import sys`, `sys.path.insert(0, '../mymodule')`, `import file1`.
The imports in `file1`: `if 'unittest' in locals():
 from links import RawTextLink, RenderedTextLink    
else:
 from .links import RenderedTextLink, RenderedTextLink`
What did I make wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was completely wrong. What I have to do is **importing the whole package to the pythonpath and then using absolute imports**. (In the tests file, of course.)

That means:

- there is no trouble with relative imports in my module
- I don't have to mess up in my module just to be able to do tests (Which is no good idea as [Vasili Syrakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851986/vasili-syrakis) said.
- I can acces the module from within the tests

---

So I use `from . import somefile` in `mymodule`. To the tests I added this code:

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../django-mymodule')
from mymodule import file1
```

---

Thank you for the tipps!